# Insert tab character into SlateJS text editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

**How to insert tab characters into SlateJS?**

So inserting `&emsp;` is a tab character, however, when inserting this as text, it appears as the literal characters `&emsp;` not the text with a tab spacing.

```
// Don't work, inserts literal characters
const insertText = (editor, format) => {
    Editor.insertText(editor, `&emsp;')
}
```

Is there any simple way to insert a `&emsp;` and have Slatejs recognise it as the html, not as pure text?

Based on my rough understanding, it might be I'll need to serialise and deserialise html before inserting it. Maybe even inserting `<pre>    </pre>` blocks with the spacing included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dawned on me I could insert 4 spaces instead of a tab character... Although, this isn't perfect, you have to backspace 4 times instead of a single time like tabs.

```
const insertText = (editor, format) => {
    Editor.insertText(editor, '    ')
}
```

Could also insert tab space characters in the insert text, like [the tabs in this article](https://www.html.am/html-codes/character-codes/html-tab-code.cfm), can't copy paste their tabs as SO turns it into spaces. Seems to work perfectly fine, functionally a tab space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode convert to string. You can use horizontal tab `&#9;` as well.
https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html

```
Editor.insertText(editor, '\u2003'.toString()) // &emsp;
Editor.insertText(editor, '\u0009'.toString()) // &#9;
```

If you want to wrap it in a span, ie render as `<span style={{whiteSpace: "pre"}}>&#9;</span>` you can do so with marks.

```
renderLeaf={props => {
  const leafStyle = props.leaf.pre && {whiteSpace: "pre"}
  return <span style={leafStyle}>{children}</span>
}}

Editor.insertNodes(editor, {
  text: '\u0009'.toString(),
  pre: true
})
```